NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenSettings$SettingsHolder
When I upgraded the dependency org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils from 3.5.1 to 4.0.1, I started getting the error below when the method kieBuilder.buildAll(); gets executed.
Error:
NoClassDefFound Could not initialize class org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenSettings$SettingsHolder
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/pull/XmlPullParserException

pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
    <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
    <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Java Code:
@Service
public class MyClass {
    private KieServices kieServices;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        kieServices = KieServices.get();
    }

    private KieBuilder build(String namespace, String ruleSet, String content) {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices
                .newKieFileSystem()
                .generateAndWritePomXML(generateReleaseId(namespace, ruleSet))
                .write("src/main/resources/" + UUID.randomUUID() + "/ruleset.drl", content);
    
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    
        kieBuilder.buildAll();
    
        return kieBuilder;
    }

    private ReleaseId generateReleaseId(String namespace, String ruleSet) {
        return kieServices.newReleaseId(namespace, ruleSet, "1");
    }
}

Any idea why I started getting this error?

Because you broke a dependency requirement when you upgraded. Figure out what used to be providing that class and add that dependency directly to your pom. This doesn't have anything to do with drools, spring, spring-boot, etc. -- just plain old maven dependency management.

Try to add this dependency to your maven pom:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-xml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>

This adds the Plexus XML Utils to your dependencies.
